# array print from function - java

Tags: java

I am trying to print an array of some prime numbers which are divided by a number, the output I get for this code:

> [J@15db9742

How can I print the array I get by the function.

```
public static long[] primes(int n) {
    int count = 0;
    long arr1[] = new long[n];
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        boolean prime = true;
        if (n % i == 0)
            for (int j = 2; j < i && prime; j++) {
                if (i % j == 0) prime = false;
            }
        if (prime && n % i == 0) {
            arr1[count] = i;
            System.out.println(arr1[count]);
            count++;
        }
    }

    long arr[] = new long[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = arr1[i];
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));`

Comment: @pbabcdefp answer is the best.

Answer (score 4):

Array is ***reference type***.

And you have to use utility class [`Arrays`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) for printing arrays:

> [Arrays.toString(array)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(int[]))

for ***multidimensional arrays***:

> [Arrays.deepToString(array)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString(java.lang.Object[]))

**BTW**
Small suggestions you can use some optimization instead ***for loop***:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = arr1[i];
    }
```

better to use [`System.arraycopy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)):

> System.arraycopy(arr1, 0, arr, 0, arr.length);

Comment: Or, just `return arr1.clone()`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman It will work, but for ***multidimensional arrays*** `clone()` fails.

Comment: If this problem involved multidimensional arrays, I wouldn't have suggested it?  But this question doesn't seem to need generalization to multidimensional arrays.  (Also, `System.arraycopy` doesn't work any better for multidimensional arrays.)

Comment: @LouisWasserman `arr1` and `arr` have different lengths so `clone` won't work.

Comment: @pbabcdefp: Ah, I follow, good catch.  Then you want `Arrays.copyOf(arr1, count)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(long n: arr)
 System.out.println(n);
```